# Make part of text bold (up to first '/')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make text bold inside elements with class="descTD" up to the first forward slash (/) like so:

**before slash** / after slash

the text is inside td:

```
 <td class="descTD">My text / is this</td>
```

I'm a javascript jQuery newbe. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: is your text wrapped with some div,span,a etc?

Comment: yes, <td class="descTD">My text / is this</td>. Just added that to the question. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use something like this :

```js
    if($("#textme").text().indexOf("/")>0){
        var t=$("#textme").text();
        $("#textme").html("<b>" + t.substring(0,t.indexOf('/')-1) + "</b>" +     t.substring(t.indexOf('/')));
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textme">before slash / after slash</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

JS --

```
//get the text to manipulate
var str = $('#element').text(),

    //get the position of the first forward slash
    pos = str.indexOf('/');

//set the HTML of the element to include a span that has a class to alter the display of the text
//(just for what's before the first forward slash)
$('#element').html('<span class="bold">' + str.substr(0, pos) + '</span>' + str.substr(pos));​
```

CSS --

```
.bold {
    font-weight : bold;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Vx4fL/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do it

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/Eh2ym/

```
$(selector).html(function(i, old){
   var htm= old.split('/'); 
  return '<strong>'+ htm[0] +'</strong>'+htm[1];    
 })
```

​

Comment: btw, if there's more '/' in the text, this will display a part of it.

Comment: true...not a lot of details given

Comment: This removes slashes and breaks when there's no slash

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting the value inside of some tag (span, div, etc)

```
var bolded = $("#my_selector").text().replace(/$(.*?)\/(.*)/,"<strong>$1</strong>/$2");
```

The regular expresion says match from the beginning up to the first / and store that in capture group 1, match the rest and put in capture group 2, then build a string that wraps the value in group 1 with `<strong>` and `</strong>` and tack the / and the rest back on.

I forget how jQuery lets you change the content, but I think it's

```
$("my_selector").text(bolded);
```